# How to stack links vertically using CSS only

Tags: html, css

How do you stack HTML tags like hyperlinks vertically without using HTML list or breaks?

Example:

`<a href "#">A</a> <a href "#">B</a> <a href "#">C</a>`

#### Output

A

B

C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `block` to your anchor element

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: what if you need to use float is their a workaround to to allow this?

Comment: Use float in what regard? Provide an example and I’ll do my best to help

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) for the parent element, like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    ...
</div>

.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there.   I like this solution better because block mostly works with div tags, whereas this will work always.